# ChromeDriver unreachable browser exception on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a set of selenium tests with the chromedriver plugin on Jenkins.

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

How in the java code do I get chrome driver to look on the Jenkins server for its exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it in Java. Just make sure to include the ChromeDriver location in your PATH environment variable as [described here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).

There is an example how to do it in Java by *setting* a system property - but I won't recommend it. A better way would be to set the variable when invoking the JVM like this `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/another/path/to/chromedriver`. But the easiest way is still adjusting the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, check the Port of HUB and NODE. I changed it to test something and forgot to change it back. Make sure the PORT of HUB and NODE is same as mentioned in your code.